# How I can move JavaDoc from master branch to gh-pages branch on GitHub using EGit and Eclipse?

Tags: java, github, javadoc

I have a java project hosted on a GitHub. And I want to allow see JavaDoc HTML-page for this hosting. For this purpose I create `gh-pahes` branch.

How I can *easy* move/commit JavaDoc (that created into `master` branch) into `gh-pages` branch using EGit and Eclipse IDE? I regenerate JavaDoc often and want find way to easy commit new version JavaDoc to `gh-pages` but working into `master` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found not so good solution as I want, but it is works:

1. Create *gh-pages* branch in a GitHub.
2. Checkout this branch.
3. Switch from *gh-pages* to *master* and generate *javadoc*.
4. Commit *javadocs*.
5. Switch from *master* to *gh-pages* branch.
6. You can see that *gh-pages* branch includes *javadoc* folder.
7. Just commit this folder into *gh-pages*.
8. **See how to update!**

**How to update:**

1. In *master* branch **remove all *javadoc* directory** and **regenerate *javadoc***.
2. Commit **only the generated *javadoc*!**.
3. Switch from *master* to *gh-pages* branch.
4. **Remove old *javadoc* and commit this changes!**
5. Right-click on you project and select *Team* -> *Show in History*.
6. Found you commit with *javadoc* from *master* branch.
7. Right-click on this commit and select *Cherry Pick*.

Thats is all! Now you commit from *master* branch copy to *gh-pages* branch!

I don't know **WHY** I need using special branch for access to my HTML docs in the GitHub?! Use Google Code is **MORE** useful!

Answer (score 2):

This is not in Eclipse, but this is how I do the move in command line without a second clone of the repo.  First I configure my javadoc plugin to generate the docs in the folder "apidocs" in my project directory using this in my pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     ...
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportOutputDirectory>apidocs</reportOutputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
```

Then I add "apidocs" to my .gitignore in master.   Then to make and move the javadocs, I do the following - starting in master:

```
mvn javadoc:javadoc
tar cfv apidocs.tar apidocs
git checkout gh-branches
tar xfv apidocs.tar
git commit -a
git push
rm apidocs.tar
git checkout master
```

The trick is that the tar file (which never ends up in the repo) does survive the switch between branches - whereas it seems as though the changes to apidocs files in the folder hierarchy vanish when I switch branches.

Nicely when I switch back to master - the apidocs folder is gone.

Comment: I guess you ment `gh-pages` instead of `gh-branches` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a second clone of your repository with a checked out `gh-pages` branch. Then you can easily move and commit your generated files without switching between the master and the gh-pages branch.